# merge commits from one branch into another one

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

With bitbucket and Atlassian SourceTree I did this:

```
01/July/2015  - Create the branch 'Branch01' from ' Develop'.

[ ... ]       - Work on 'Branch01'.

01/Agost/2015 - Create the branch 'Brancho02' from 'Develop'.

[ ... ]       - Work on 'Branch01' and 'Branch02'.

01/Oct/2015   - Merge 'Branch02' into 'Develop'.
```

I want to get the commits from Branch02 into Branch01 without merging 'Branch01' in to ' Develop'

How can I do this?

If, I find a lot of errors when I do the merge, can I undo these changes?

Comment: Do you want to get _specific_ commits or all of them?

Comment: @GSWV I want to get all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can execute the following command

```
git checkout Branch01
git merge Branch02
```

And there you've got it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want any specific commit from Branch02 into Branch01

```
git cherry-pick 'commit-id'
```

If you need all of the commit into Branch01

```
git checkout Branch01

git merge Branch02
```

So brings all the changes of Branch02 into Branch01

Unfortunately if you find errors or conflicts you reset your merge just by doing this

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

so your merge will be reverted and Branch01 will go to its original state

Even you can use

```
git reset --merge
```

Hope your work go smooth. You can undo the changes.